# how to scrape deeply embeded links with python beautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to build a spider/web crawler for academic purposes to grab text from academic publications and append related links to a URL stack. I'm trying to crawl 1 website called 'PubMed'. I can't seem to grab the links I need though. Here is my code with an example page, this page should be representative of others in their database:

```
 website = 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=mtap+prmt'
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import requests
 r = requests.get(website)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
```

I have broken the html tree down into several variables just for readability so that it can all fit on 1 screen width.

```
 key_text = soup.find('div', {'class':'grid'}).find('div',{'class':'col twelve_col nomargin shadow'}).find('form',{'id':'EntrezForm'})
 side_column = key_text.find('div', {'xmlns:xi':'http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude'}).find('div', {'class':'supplemental col three_col last'})
 side_links = side_column.find('div').findAll('div')[1].find('div', {'id':'disc_col'}).findAll('div')[1]

 for link in side_links:
      print link
```

if you look at the html source code using chrome inspect element there should be several other nested divs with links within 'side_links'. However the above code produces the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/ballbag/Copy/web_scraping/google_search.py", line 22, in <module>
 side_links = side_column.find('div').findAll('div')[1].find('div',      {'id':'disc_col'}).findAll('div')[1]
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

if you go to the url there is a column on the right called 'related links' containing the urls that I wish to scrape. But I can't seem to get to them. There is a statement saying  under the div i am trying to get into and I suspect this has something to do with it. Can anyone help grab these links? I'd really appreciate any pointers

Comment: I don't see any `related links ` on that page

Comment: sorry 'related citations in pubmed'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the side bar is loaded with an additional asynchronous request.

The idea here would be to:

- maintain a web-scraping session using [`requests.Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=session#requests.Session)
- parse the url that is used for getting the side bar
- follow that link and get the links from the `div` with `class="portlet_content"`

Code:

```
from urlparse import urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


base_url = 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov'
website = 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=mtap+prmt'

# parse the main page and grab the link to the side bar
session = requests.Session()
soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(website).content)

url = urljoin(base_url, soup.select('div#disc_col a.disc_col_ph')[0]['href'])

# parsing the side bar
soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(url).content)

for a in soup.select('div.portlet_content ul li.brieflinkpopper a'):
    print a.text, urljoin(base_url, a.get('href'))
```

Prints:

```
The metabolite 5'-methylthioadenosine signals through the adenosine receptor A2B in melanoma. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25087184
Down-regulation of methylthioadenosine phosphorylase (MTAP) induces progression of hepatocellular carcinoma via accumulation of 5'-deoxy-5'-methylthioadenosine (MTA). http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21356366
Quantitative analysis of 5'-deoxy-5'-methylthioadenosine in melanoma cells by liquid chromatography-stable isotope ratio tandem mass spectrometry. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18996776
...
Cited in PMC http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/pmid/23265702/citedby/?tool=pubmed
```

Comment: I could not even find what the OP was looking for!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham turn on your imagination or start reading thoughts through the internet! :) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, your code words perfectly. Just for my understanding though, where did you find the 'href' in the line: "url = urljoin(base_url, soup.select('div#disc_col a.disc_col_ph')[0]['href'])". I can navigate to the div but 'chromes inspect element' shows no links in that section of html. I cannot see the 'a' link in div#disc_col although your code works. Nor can I find the relevant section in the base url. If you could recommend any articles to aid my understanding that would be great. Otherwise, thanks anyway.

Comment: @user3062260 this is what you would not find in the browser since the browser can modify the initially retrieved HTML applying the content it receives from additional async requests, or executing javascript code. What you get with `requests.get()` or `session.get()` though is the initial HTML page - this is there you can find the link `div#disc_col a.disc_col_ph`. In other words, print out `session.get(website).content` and look for the link. Hope that clears things up a bit.

Comment: @user3062260 well, you can see that initial HTML in the browser too - open up browser developer tools, network tab and inspect the response of the very first request.